# Intuition behind the noncentral chi square as Poisson mixing

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

It is known (cf. [Wikipedia, Noncentral_chi_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution)) that the non-central chi-square distribution with k degrees of freedom is a Poisson weighted mixture of central chi-squared distributions).

There are many proofs but all are basically the same (see same ref section "Derivation of the pdf" for a sketch and here [libre stats](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Book%3A_Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/05%3A_Special_Distributions/5.09%3A_Chi-Square_and_Related_Distribution) for a freely accessible complete proof).

I'm looking for the intuition behind this result, that is, a way to interpret and explain it. Otherwise such the result seems kind of accident. Any idea ?

best,
G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Patnaik](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/36/1-2/202/200823) writes on p. 203:

> The [non-central $\chi^2$ distribution] has been [sic] obtained by [Fisher, R. A. (1928). Proc. Roy. Soc. A, **121**, 654]
> as a particular case of the distribution of the multiple correlation
> coefficient. A purely analytical proof was given by [Tang, P. C. (1938). Statist. Res. Mem. **2,** 126]. [...] We
> give a direct geometrical derivation of the
> [non-central $\chi^2$ distribution].

The geometric derivation by Patnaik uses a series expansion of the density, which is equivalent to the series expansion of the characteristic or moment generating function in the usual quick derivation of the non-central $\chi^2$ distribution as a Poisson mixture of central $\chi^2$ distributions.

So, I think there has never been any "intuition behind this result" -- just a lucky and rather simple analytical observation.

Comment: Yes, I saw the paper and some others (for instance Kerridge Aust J Stat 7(1965)37-39 ) and there is no intuition behind just series expansion. But I still find weird that all constants line up so remarkably, My idea was to look for an intuition by decomposing somehow chi-square as a sum, the same for Poisson, both have additive properties...

Comment: @Gabriel : Intuition is defined as the "faculty of knowing or understanding something without reasoning or proof" (https://www.thefreedictionary.com/intuition). It seems very likely that there has never been such intuition here. As for "all constants lin[ing] up so remarkably", I guess you mean the Poisson mixture. But the Poisson  probabilities are just the terms of the normalized Maclaurin series for the exponential function, which are quite ubiquitous.

Comment: I guess you are right...